# Problem with Tag-it jQuery plugin form input array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, input

i try to use [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it) jquery plugin.
it convert entry tag to:

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="tag1" name="item[tags][]">
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="tag2" name="item[tags][]">
```

when form submit, it will send to another page, the problem is that i want use "item[tags][]" in loop but using foreach just give me error for invalid arguments. can any one help me with this loop. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" style="display:none;" value="tag1,tag2" name="tags">
```

jQuery:

```
 $('input[name="tags"]').tagit();
```

You will see these two tags: `tag1` and `tag2`
and if you submit it you will get the tags separated by a comma in for example php in `$_GET["tags"]`